# How do I use the GUI to drag folders?

Tags: 16.04, gui

I created a folder /sharedfolder and inside it i have folders and files. I want to move the folders and files around using drag and drop but I cant. I have to `sudo mv`. How do i enable drag and drop ?

Comment: the fact that you need to use `sudo` suggests that you do not have write permission in the destination. What are you trying to move and where?

Comment: its all within the /sharedfolder that i created.  So you are saying that i need to edit the permissions. I will check that out.

Answer (score 0):

First the answer:

When you created the directory under the `/` (root directory) you need to become root user to do it, so was created with `root:root` ownership and specific permissions

Ex:

```
sudo mkdir /foo
sudo ls -la /foo
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 nov 19 13:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 4096 nov 19 13:35 ..
```

As you can see this foo directory its owned by root and is the only user with write permission on it is because of that you need to become root by using `sudo` to write files on it

Second my opinion:

As Linux have a quite well defined directory hierarchy structure you should probably create this directory under some other place than `/`.
If you want to share a directory used by someone you probably want to create this shared resource under the `$HOME` `/home/foo_user` directory or `/media/foo_user` for a removable device